# Which player class is created by better hierachy?

Tags: c++, class-hierarchy

Which class is more acceptable for future implementations? Assault predator(multiple inheritance) or queen(multi-level hierarchy)?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdlib.h> 

class living
{
public:
    int hitpoints;
    int adaptation;
};

class alien:public living
{
public:
    bool tail;
    bool claws;
    bool legs;
    bool secondary_jaws;
    bool acid_blood;
    alien(){adaptation=1000;hitpoints=50;}
};

class queen:public alien
{
public:
    bool ovipositor;
    bool tertiary_jaws;
};

class predator
{
public:
    bool legs;
    bool arms;
    bool glowstick_blood;

};

class assault_predator:public living,public predator
{
public:
    bool plasma_caster;
    bool infrared_vision;
    assault_predator(){hitpoints=150;adaptation=33;}
};


int main()
{
    assault_predator player1;
    queen player2;

    getchar();
    return 0;
  }
```

As seen, assault predator is derived from **living** and **predator** separately. Queen is derived from **alien** and alien is derived from **living**.

**Question:** Which one is more logical in terms of **programming and class hierarchy**.

What are cons&pros of these players?

Comment: Instead of having five booleans in the `alien` class and 2 booleans in the `queen` class, clearly you should have 32 different alien classes and 128 different queen classes ;)

Comment: Asking "cons and pros" and "which one is more acceptable" could not more fit the concept of a question "likely to solicit debate."  Is there anything more specific you're trying to research or learn here?

Comment: I don't know what is "logical in terms of programming and class hierarchy" but I'm pretty sure predator should be derived form living. Class hierarchies **should reflect your problem domain**. Multiple inheritance can give you ambiguity problems, but if there is no way around you should use it.

Comment: On a more serious note, please stop building large inheritance graphs just because you can. This isn't the 90s anymore. We know better now.

Comment: "Class hierarchies **should reflect your problem domain**." And this looks like quite an interesting problem domain.

Comment: Just about adding different classes of predator and alien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are just different. Multiple inheritance allows you to combine separate objects into one. Multi-level inheritance allows further specification of type.